# Unable to CANCEL or DELETE a Scheduled Mailing (Mosaico is installed)

Tags: civimail, mailing, mosaico

With either a Send Now or Scheduled mailing (Mosaico created) I unable to Cancel or Delete the Mailing in the Find Mailings page.

Using WordPress 4.9.4, CiviCRM 4.7.30 and the following related extensions: 
Angular Profiles (org.civicrm.angularprofiles) version 4.7.31-1.1.0
FlexMailer (org.civicrm.flexmailer) version 0.2-alpha5
CiviCRM Bootstrap theme (org.civicrm.shoreditch) version 0.1-alpha16
Mosaico (uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico) version 2.0-beta3.1512698300

When I click Cancel for the Scheduled mailing on the Find Mailings page, I received the following dialog:
[image]

And then the following dialog:
[image]

Then it returns me to the Find Mailings page with no change to the mailing.  I've tried to refresh the screen also to see if there was a delay.

## April 4/22/2018 Update:

Providing the following additional information to this problem as it might be related.  I am also unable to delete a mailing using the DELETE action on the *Draft / Unscheduled Mailings* listing.  I AM able to delete the mailing if I click CONTINUE from the listing page and then select DELETE DRAFT when viewing the individual mailing.  The link that the DELETE action is posting when on the listing page is:

http://myorganization.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/browse&action=delete&mid=16&reset=1&confirmed=1

and the page says that the Link has expired:

[image: The link you followed has expired. Please try again.]

Comment: have you checked in your ConfigAndLog files relating to this? and if you don't know how to easily access them you could try the Log Viewer extension - https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer

Comment: We face the same problem with a WordPress 4.9.6/CiviCRM 4.7.29 site.

Comment: Hi Charles - a 'we have the same problem' comment isn't an Answer so will get downvoted -maybe you do not yet have enough reputation to Comment but if you engage with SE a bit more you will quickly get that I hope. FYI, we did some work to make a PAUSE function available - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11803

Comment: I ran into this recently, do you happen to have or had the plugin [Events Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/) installed?

Comment: Andrei yes, we do have the Events Manager plugin installed

Comment: @ChaosBuster one of the Events Manger updates changed some timezone settings, but for some reason the upgrade did not trigger/run (I have not dug into the issue). Navigate to this url on your site `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=event&page=events-manager-options&action=update&update_action=timezone-backcompat` if you see a description about the timezone settings with a button to *Finalise Upgrade*, proceed with the upgrade, after that you should be able to delete mailings again.

Comment: BINGO!  Thanks, Andrei, that solved it.  You might want to add as an Answer.

Comment: @ChaosBuster good to hear, answer added.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the [Events Manger](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/) plugin try navigating to `https://yoursite.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=event&page=events-manager-options&action=update&update_action=timezone-backcompat` if you see a description about the timezone settings with a button to **Finalise Upgrade** on that page, it's likely the issue is caused by a non completed update of the Events Manager plugin.

Click on Finalise Upgrade, after the upgrade is completed you should be able to cancel/delete scheduled/unscheduled mailings.

Comment: Thanks, Andrei, worked for our setup!  Able to Cancel and Delete mailings now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling pop up forms at Administer -- customize data and screens --- display preferences -- enable popup forms

If it still does not work with pop up forms enabled - have you tried disabling wordpress plugins one at a time to see if there are any conflicts? I was not able to replicate this on two wordpress civicrm sites with a similar setup (using shoreditch alpha 17, but I doubt that makes a difference.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @themak . The Enable Popup Forms was checked.

Comment: @ChaosBuster did you figure out the issue?  Also - do you use wordfence?

Comment: No, still a problem...and just updated to 5.0.2.  Yes, we use WordFence.

Answer (score 0):

Fuzion did some work to add some new functionality namely a PAUSE function for mailings - github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11803 - needs some more input and testing if anyone is interested

Comment: Thanks, Pete. I would be interested if able to get some time.  Is it in an update?